# Get iPhone location on loading

Tags: iphone, location, alert

I have set my app to initially request location as soon as it loads but the first time the app is used the dialog box pops that asks permission from the user appears for a brief second then disappears as the view finished loading (or something). This all happens too quick for the user to say "yep, that's ok". Where should I put the following code to make the location permission popup appear the first time the user loads the app?

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] init];

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
[locationManager setPurpose:@"A fun way to record where you've answered the questions and how you did at each location."];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
location = [locationManager location];
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

Thank you,
Bren

Comment: We need context. Where are you performing the above code?

Comment: That permission dialog shouldn't be closing itself. When I do my location manager fire-up in my App Delegate's `ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, it brings up the permission dialog and blocks until the user replies to it. That's what a modal dialog like that is for.

Comment: Sorry, I had it in the viewDidLoad event of my first view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many places where you can put this code. Basically, it needs to be after you have finished to load the user interface.

It can be in your AppDelegate, as long as it's after the `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` call.
It can also be in the method `viewDidAppear:` of your first viewController. If you choose this option, keep in mind that `viewDidAppear:` can be called many times.

Comment: I can't find a MakeKeyAndVisible part of my app but I did try putting it in viewDidAppear (within the first view controller to appear) but that still causes the quick popup and disappear alert request.

Comment: Which template did you used when you created the application?

Comment: It was the tab bar application in ios 5 SDK.

Comment: Then the last line of your method - application: didFinishLaunching: is [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; Do you see it?

Comment: That line isn't there but I'll add it and try again when I get home from work. Thanks for the help, it's much appreciated.